# Getting a zip file with R httr package: file is empty

Tags: r, httr

I am downloading a zip file from a site that uses basic authentication. The download seems to be going OK but when I try the unzip the file, it turns out to be empty. When I download the file by hand, it has several folders and files in it.

Here's what I am doing:

```
library(httr)

dest <- paste0(getwd(), "/data/weekly_2017-02-18.zip")
GET("https://www.example.com/weeklydata/weekly_2017-02-18.zip", 
     authenticate("myemail", "mypassword", "basic"), 
     write_disk(dest, overwrite = TRUE))
unzip(dest) # <-- THIS FAILS
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Solved! It turns out I did not need the authenticate function for this part of the site.

Answer (score 0):

unzip(dest)) <-- there is an extra closing bracket here

use:

unzipped <- unzip(dest)

Comment: I'm sorry, the extra bracket was a typo. It wasn't there in my original code.

Comment: can you see if the zip is not damaged, if the response status is 200? unzip merely will list all the contents (names) of the parent zip. is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Hm, response status is 400 (bad request). I have yet to find out why.